# Parsing redundant information with Joda Time

Tags: jodatime, simpledateformat, java-time

I am dealing with strings such as the following: `0022 GMT (0822 HKT) July 21, 2016`

Obviously these strings specify the time of the day twice for two different time zones. Can the pattern syntax of Joda Time's `DateTimeFormat.forPattern()` handle this kind of redundant information?

One possibility would be to just ignore one of the two time expressions `0022 GMT` and `0822 HKT`. This would require some kind of wildcard that could match the part of the time expression to be ignored which would look something like `Hm z '(*)' MMM dd, y`.

Does such a wildcard or anything else that could parse the above time string exist in Joda Time's pattern syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to ignore the potentially ambivalent part (repeating hour, minute and zone name in other zone), you have to write your own [DateTimeParser](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeParser.html) in **Joda-Time**:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf =
    new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("HHmm 'GMT' (").append(
        new DateTimeParser() {
            @Override
            public int estimateParsedLength() {
                return 10;
            }
            @Override
            public int parseInto(DateTimeParserBucket bucket, String text, int position) {
                int pos = position;
                while (text.charAt(pos) != ')') {
                    pos++;
                }
                return pos;
            }
        }
    )
    .appendPattern(") MMMM dd, yyyy")
    .toFormatter()
    .withLocale(Locale.US)
    .withZoneUTC();

String input = "0022 GMT (0822 HKT) July 21, 2016";    
DateTime dt = dtf.parseDateTime(input);
System.out.println("Joda: " + dt); // 2016-07-21T00:22:00.000Z
```

For your information, I don't see any way to do this in **Java-8** (without input preprocessing), see this example which will throw an exception even with using optional sections. Java-8 lacks a mechanism to write your own parser.

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = 
  DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HHmm z ([HHmm z]) MMMM dd, uuuu", Locale.US);
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(input, dtf); // throws exception!!!
// java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: 
// Text '0022 GMT (0822 HKT) July 21, 2016' could not be parsed at index 10
```

Side note: When you might explore my library **Time4J** which offers an alternative and more performant parse engine suitable for Java-8, then it offers an easier solution than Joda-Time, see this small [gist example](https://gist.github.com/MenoData/74e8e8d87d91669203ab4cae8e5330b1).

Else writing a **hackish workaround** using string preprocessing is always possible (interesting when a 3rd-party-library is not allowed):

```
String input = "0022 GMT (0822 HKT) July 21, 2016";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
boolean markedForRemoval = false;
for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
    char c = input.charAt(i);
    if (c == ')') {
        markedForRemoval = false;
    }
    if (!markedForRemoval) {
        sb.append(c);
    }
    if (c == '(') {
        markedForRemoval = true;
    }
}
input = sb.toString();
System.out.println(input); // 0022 GMT () July 21, 2016
// continue parsing the changed input based on a formatter of your choice
```